# Deleting row of listview populated by custom cursor adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, android-cursoradapter

I have a custom cursor adapter CAdapter having the following lines of code:

```
public class CAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public CAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        TextView titleTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        titleTV.setText("#"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1)))+" "+
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2)))); 
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item_layout, parent, false); 
        return retView;
    }

}
```

row_item_layout.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/heartIV"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Example application"
        android:textSize="26sp" 
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/heartIV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/listTitle"
        android:src="@drawable/heart"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" 
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The activity FavListActivity displays the list. Its layout file is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.xkcdreader.FavListActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/favL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="452dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headingTV" >

    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headingTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="Favourites"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to show Actionbar containing a delete option when a row is selected (by long clicking it). On pressing delete button the row should disappear ,database updated, and the list should refresh accordingly. How to do this. I searched on the internet but couldn't find satisfactory answers.

Comment: You can better store the cursor data into an arraylist and you can create a normal baseadapter their row removal will easier

Answer (score 0):

Try Some Like That:

Listview Click Listner

```
favL.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                General.deleteRecordID = DatabaseHelper.idArrayList.get(arg3);
                Log.i("Item Click", "Item Clicked " + arg3);
                itemClickDialog();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Alert Dialog:

```
public void itemClickDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemclick_dialogbox,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main));

    builder.setView(customView);

    final Dialog dialog = builder.create();

    dialog.show();
    TextView tvEdit = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvEdit);
    TextView tvPaidBill = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPaidBill);
    TextView tvDeleteReminder = (TextView) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.tvDeleteReminder);

    tvEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intentAddItemActivity = new Intent(context,
                    AddItemActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentAddItemActivity);
            dialog.cancel();
            // Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked Edit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            // .show();
        }
    });

    tvPaidBill.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked Paid Bill",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            // .show();
        }
    });

    tvDeleteReminder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dbHelper.deleteRecordFromUpcomingBills(General.deleteRecordID);
            dialog.cancel();
            Intent intentUpcomingBillsActivity = new Intent(context,
                    UpcomingBillsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentUpcomingBillsActivity);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

Delete record query:

```
public void deleteRecordFromUpcomingBills(String deleteRecordID) {
    Log.i("deleteRecordID", deleteRecordID);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String sqlQuery="DELETE FROM Upcoming_Bills WHERE ID="+ deleteRecordID;
    Log.e("sqlQuery", sqlQuery);
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

    }
    db.close();

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I want to implement

Comment: set your delete query in database, get the row position on click that save to variable, that variable send to the query and reload your activity

Comment: My question is not focused on how to delete but how to implement action bar

Comment: I have asked 3 questions in this post. How to implement action bar, how to delete a record and how to subsequently refresh the list. You are focusing on the delete part only. Try to read question properly before downvoting. I you are not sure about how to implement action bar for a listview do not answer. Thanks.

Comment: In question Title You only ask delete, edit your title, thanks

Comment: Question title is meant only to summarize whatever a person is going to ask. One cannot add whole lot of details in title of a post. The question description part of the post is the real question.

Comment: Can you undo your downvoting. I can't ask any new questions now.

Comment: done, now upvote my answer, there clear to question refresh and delete record